# What happens if a character suffers four equal wounds?

Tags: burning-wheel, injury

The Physical Tolerance Grayscale on the BW character sheet has three circles for marking injuries for each coordinate. What happens if one suffers more than three wounds to the same coordinate? Are there only three circles just due to the design of the sheet or is it a hard limit on the number of identical wounds one can suffer?

---

### Example

A character with Light Wound threshold of B5 gets hit four times for B5 each time. Where is the fourth hit marked on the PTGS and what are its effects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a limitation of the sheet that there's only three bubbles for each wound level, but this limitation usually doesn't come up during play.

A B5 is usually at least a Light wound, receiving such a wound means taking a Steel test (with wound penalties for all wounds sustained, including this new one), and failing Steel tests by a large margin usually ends the conflict. If their total penalties is at least the lowest of their stats, they're also incapacitated.